# change view (storyboard) after zbar didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo inside a tab

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode4.5, zbar-sdk, uitabcontroller

I'm still new to programming on the iPhone, and have researched my problem, but have no luck with any of the solutions.

I have managed to follow [ZBar SDK Integration tutorial](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html) to have a working app at the end, inside a tab controller.

What I am trying to do is, move the results to a separate ViewController.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;

    ProductViewController *product = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ProductView"];

    product.resultImage = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    product.resultText = symbol.data;

    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:product animated:YES];
}
```

The problem I'm having with the code is that product view controller never displayed.

Using Xcode 4.5, iOS 6 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the above approach and instead added function on my navigigation controller to handle displaying.

Displaying Scan:

`[[self targetController] displayNewObject:scan];`

On the receiving end:

```
- (void)displayNewObject:(_Scan *)scan
{
    self.scan = scan;
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ShowScanDetail" sender: self];
    self.scan = nil;
}
```

Comment: If anyone is after more details then I can post more

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductView"];
[reader presentViewController:newTopViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I didn't get an answer to my issue, so I had to rewrote my problem into something more manageable.

I have updated my question with the solution I came up with